# Different babel presets for backend and frontend but for same env

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have nodejs project with react frontend part, and I want to use babel for backend server (to have import / export, and some additional features like 'decorators', object-rest-spread etc)

Also I want to use babel for react frontend project but with different set of presets / plugins. 
On the backend I have latest (8.2) nodejs so it's already know classes, async/await etc which shouldn't be transpiled.
But at frontend I'm targeting IE11 so I have to enable a lot of plugins. 
So if I have single .babelrc config for frontend and backend I'm getting overtranspiled backend code.

I know there is an 'env' option for babel config but in describe case I have same 'env'. 
For now I'm ended with two configs: 
one in package.json and one inside of webpack.config (babel-loader options). 
However I don't like result because its may confuse new developers. 
He can found babel config inside of package.json  and think that this is the only config, trying to add / modify something and struggling why it doesn't affect frontend part.

There is also some problems with such setup:

Jest can't read babel settings from webpack.config so I have to define additional "env": "test" in .babelrc just for jest. 
And this lead to unnecessary transpiling backend during tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way I've approached the problem in my projects. It's *best* to keep the two separate, and perhaps be explicit about which one you're using in a given context. You are targeting two very different environments, and it makes sense to have two different configuration files. Where you building an webview version from the same codebase, you'd have a separate config for that as well. And so on for each "environment" you'd have.

It might pose problems for newer developers, but I'd argue that having `if (is_in_client_mode) ? 'one_config_value' : 'another_config_value'` spread around is just as bad, without the benefits of having two files.

Comment: Having two different configs is definitely a solution. But how to deal with jest and it's inability to use custom babel config?